# what is the conventional way of using Backbone.js and Underscore.js with Grunt?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gruntjs, underscore.js

I am creating a grunt project that uses backbone.js and underscore.js
I've included these 2 using `npm install backbone --save-dev` and `npm install underscore --save-dev`. Clearly it is now in my package.json.

I just want to know if there is a conventional way of using `backbone.js` and `underscore.js` together with `grunt`

Like does it need to use `require.js` to include backbone and underscore in my `gruntfile`, or
an html script tag will do ( `<script src="path/underscore.js"><script>` and `<script src="path/backbone.js"><script>`) ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if there's a 'proper' way of including Backbone.js and Underscore.js so what I did was the simple `<script src="path/underscore.js"></script>` and `<script src="path/backbone.js"></script>` in my html.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project with a similar setup. I found the [grunt-require](https://github.com/asciidisco/grunt-requirejs) plugin was perfect for what I needed.

Now in my `Gruntfile` I've got:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    requirejs: {
      compile: {
        options: {
          almond: true, //almond is one of the plugin dependencies
          inlineText: true,
          out: 'site/build/myapp.min.js',
          logLevel: 0,
          baseUrl: 'site',
          name: 'app',
          mainConfigFile: 'site/app.js'
        }
      },
      css: {
        options: {
          out: 'site/build/myapp.min.css',
          logLevel: 0,
          cssIn: 'site/css/myStyles.css'
        }
      }
  }
});

  // __External Tasks__
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-requirejs');

  // __Local Tasks__
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['requirejs']);
};
```

Now I can just run `grunt` and it will concat all js code into the myapp.min.js file (and do the same for all css files).

***UPDATE***

I think what you are asking about is how to set things up in your html?

You'd use this in your `index.html` file:

```
<script data-main="/app.js" src="/PATHTOREQUIRE/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Where `app.js` is your setup file, [which will look like this](https://github.com/volojs/create-template/blob/master/www/app.js)

Add backbone and underscore to the `paths` in the app.js file and then you will be able to require them.

Comment: I checked the other plugins as well, and I've used some for my needs, by including them in the package and loading them as tasks in the gruntfile but what I need is the backbone.js and underscore.js. Or do you mean that I should use require.js to include them in my gruntfile?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean...you do not include backbone.js and underscore.js in your gruntfile. If you want a totally basic setup, then download the zip versions of backbone and underscore (no need to use npm at all) and then put a script tag to the downloaded file locations (or to a CDN) in your html page. I'll also edit my answer to show you how you would load them with require.js - i.e. the non-basic way

Comment: Not really, if it's just setting things in html that shouldn't be a problem. I'm just looking for the 'proper way' if here is, since I've used grunt. But yes that's what I did, I've answered my own question, although I'm open to tips and suggestion. Thanks!